# Making calls to web-services on AWS Lambda using Java

Tags: java, http, aws-lambda

I am just trying to call an external web-service from my Java AWS Lambda function.  To do this I can't get the org.apache.http client to work.  I have the code:

```
public static String get(String get) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException{
    RequestConfig defaultRequestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setExpectContinueEnabled(true).build();
    HttpGet httpGetRequest = new HttpGet(get);
    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.copy(defaultRequestConfig).setSocketTimeout(5000).setConnectTimeout(5000).setConnectionRequestTimeout(5000).build();
    httpGetRequest.setConfig(requestConfig);

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGetRequest); <<<<<
    HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    StringBuffer all = new StringBuffer();
    if (entity != null) {
        InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(inputStream)));
        String read;
        while ((read = in.readLine()) != null){
            all.append(read);
            all.append("\n");
        }
        httpClient.close();
    }
    return all.toString();
}
```

Once it is deployed it hangs on the line `HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGetRequest); <<<<<` above.

I can prove that I have connectivity from the lambda function to the internet by setting up a Socket connection e.g. `Socket s = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("bbc.co.uk"), 80);` and I can retrieve data this way.

So the question is either what is wrong with the first code fragment which works locally but not when deployed? or is there a preferred way to call web-services from AWS lambda functions in Java (I have had a search but can't find a best practice) ?  I would prefer not to have to hand craft the HTTP requests using Sockets if I can help it.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is not working?

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is the usage of Apache HttpClient which is a large library. Switching to [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) fixed the issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use Rest Template to make this call.

Comment: Using the code:
`RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);
System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
System.out.println(response.getBody());`

If url is a HTTP url it works but HTTPS does not.

Comment: `RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());` fixed the problem.  Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
try {
    String url = "baseurl for AWS insatnce +8080/Testing/mailGenration/generate?msg=20;

    logger.log("Building HttpClient......");
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    logger.log("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.log("Exception in sendhttpclient:" + e);
}
```

Comment: above code worked for me,but its an sync call. need async call for my webservice on aws tomcat instance.